# ASP/c# Hide label in custom item template of gridview when item is null or empty

Tags: c#, gridview, conditional-statements, label

I have a gridview with:

```
<li><%#Eval("position.name") %> @ <%#Eval("employer.name")%></li>
```

The result in browser is:

```
Developer @ companyName
```

But if the position name is empty. I just see this:

```
 @ companyName
```

How can i hide the "@" sign when there is no position available to show?

Thanks!

Comment: Check for the condition 'Eval("position.name") == null' then only add <li>

Comment: try "? :"  conditional Operator.

Comment: I've tried some conditions. But still not working. Can you show my how to use eval("position.name") == null in my listitem? @V4Vendetta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li><%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("position.name") as string) ? string.Empty : Eval("position.name")+ " @ " %> <%#Eval("employer.name")%></li>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working yet
<li><%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("position.name").ToString()) ? "" : Eval("position.name") + " @ "%> <%#Eval("employer.name")%></li>
gives me null refference error. when i do:
<%#Eval("position.name")%>  <%#Eval("employer.name")%>    
then i get the data. I think i need still a small fix..

Comment: @Thomas Dekiere i've edited to fix the null issue. instead of calling "ToString()" i used "as string" which will result in a null and the test "String.IsNullOrEmpty" will work properly. I hope this helps.

Comment: "String has no definition for empty" I changed String.empty to " " and now it works! You are the best! Thanks a lot!